Connect docker compose nginx+php with local database
how to connect nginx+php i was create docker compose with my server database mysql which is on another server, but is still in one network, more or less a simple topology like this:

and my file docker compose yaml like this :
version: '3'
  services:
    nginx: 
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: doker/nginx/Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/html
      image: nginx:alpine
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      networks:
        - khailabs

    php:
      image: php:fpm-alpine
      volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/html
      networks:
        - khailabs

    networks:
      khailabs:
        driver: bridge


You should be able to just configure this in the exact same way you'd configure it without Docker.  What have you tried to set up, and what specific problem are you running into?

If without Docker it runs fine, I created nginx+php in the VM then connect to the mysql server, it run well. so is this the problem in docker network, but how to solve it? thanks

What's the problem exactly?  How are you configuring the external database location?  What error do you run into?  Can you [edit] the question to include these details?
